# Finding the probability of getting a complete set from N classes of objects in M draws

Tags: distributions, sampling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the probability of n people from a list of m people being in a random selection of x people from a list of y people?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24211/what-is-the-probability-of-n-people-from-a-list-of-m-people-being-in-a-random-se)

Let's say we have 5 kinds of marbles, 1000 of each, mixed up in a giant tub. I want to know how many I have to draw out (without replacement) before I can be 50/70/90% sure I have at least 1 of each type of marble.

I can write a script to compute every possibility in M draws for M=5 to 4001, and get the probability from that, **but** *(my point is)* I figure there must be a statistical distribution that handles this more directly. Is there a name for such a distribution?

Also, if the counts are not equal (i.e. 100 of type 1, 300 of type 2, ...), is there a distribution that handles that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asympotic approximation - considering that the number of balls is quite large.

We have $l$ types of balls, $n_i$ of each them for a total of $n_1 + \cdots +n_l=n$ (in the example, $l=5$, $n_i=1000$, $n=5000$). Let's call $x_i$ the number of balls of type $i$ that result selected in $k$ extractions. For large $n$, the $x_i$ can be approximated as independent Poisson variables with mean $\lambda_i = k \frac{ni}{n}$

We are interested in the probability that all them are greater than zero, say $P(k)$. In this approximation:

$$P(k) \approx \prod_{i=1}^l \left( 1- e^{-\lambda_i}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^l \left( 1- \exp\left(- k \frac{n_i}{n}\right)\right)  $$

and if $n_i = n_1 $ we have 
$$P(k)=\left( 1- \exp\left(- k \frac{n_1}{n}\right)\right)^l$$

or $$ k  = - \frac{n}{n_1} \log\left(1-P(k)^{1/l}\right)$$

In our example, this gives, for $P(k) =$ 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, the values $k \approx$ 10,  13,  19

Comment: This is wonderful. I could not make the leap to Poisson random variables. How can you say the variables are independent, though?

Comment: @drfloob search for "poissonization", a useful device in urns-balls models. Basically, if you throw N balls into M urns, you have a multinomial distribution, with $\sum n_i = N$ and $E(n_i)=N/M$. It can be shown that if you consider instead the (different) distribution of $M$ iid Poisson with $\lambda =N/M$, this distribution conditioned on the event $\sum n_i = N$ is exactly equivalent to the previous multinomial. And, asymtotically, that event gets more probable (informally speaking), and hence both distributions are asymtotically equivalent. This have several generalizations.

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of a name for this distribution, but the probabilities are straightforward to work out.  Not by computing all possible draws, though!  (There are far too many.)

The technique is quite general, so **let's broaden the problem statement**.  Suppose we have $n_i \gt 0$ marbles of color $j$, $j=1,2,\ldots,l$, for a total of $n=n_1+\cdots +n_l$ marbles.  For any subset of these colors $J = \{j_1,\ldots,j_s\}$, what fraction of all [simple random samples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample) of size $k$ contain exactly these colors?  The answer is immediate: it's the number of all simple random samples of size $k$ from a bag containing only marbles whose colors are in $J$, divided by the number of all simple random samples of size $k$ from the original bag:

$$f(J, k) = \binom{n_{j_1}+n_{j_2}+\cdots+n_{j_s}}{k} / \binom{n}{k}$$

By the [Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the fraction of simple random samples of size $k$ without all $l$ colors equals

$$\sum_{\varnothing \ne J \subset \{1,\ldots,l\}}(-1)^{l-\vert J\vert}f(J,k).$$

The computational effort, properly coded, is $O(2^l)$--fine for small numbers of distinct colors--and just $O(l)$ when all the $n_i$ are equal, because all terms for $J$ of a given size will be equal and only sizes $1$ through $l$ need be considered.  A *Mathematica* program that directly expresses the general formula is

```
h[x_, k_Integer] /; Total[x] >= k > 0 := 
With[{n = Total[x], l = Length[x]},
  Sum[(-1)^(l - j) Binomial[m, k]/Binomial[n, k], {j, 1, l}, {m, Total /@ Subsets[x, {j}]}]
]
```

Using it, it takes 0.015 seconds (on one core) to find `h[{1000,1000,1000,1000,1000}, k]` for `k` from 5 through 34.  Rounded, the values are

```
0.038, 0.115, 0.215, 0.323, 0.428,     0.523, 0.607, 0.679, 0.739, 0.789,
0.83,  0.863, 0.89,  0.912, 0.929,     0.943, 0.955, 0.964, 0.971, 0.977, 
0.981, 0.985, 0.988, 0.991, 0.992,     0.994, 0.995, 0.996, 0.997, 0.998
```

Here is a plot of these values:

[image: Discrete plot]

For instance, the chance that all five colors are obtained in the first five draws is $.038 = 3.8\%$ (more precisely, it's $0.038476...$).  As a check, if the sampling were *with* replacement this chance wouldn't change much and it would be computed as $1 \times \frac{4}{5} \times \frac{3}{5} \times \frac{2}{5} \times \frac{1}{5} = 0.0384$.

By inspection, **the answer to the question** (concerning the 50%/70%/90% points) is $10, 13, 18$.  For instance, $k=17$ draws have less than a 90% chance of exhibiting all five colors (the chance is $0.89$) while $k=18$ draws have at least a 90% chance (it's actually $0.912$).

Comment: your work is very good, and does solve the underlying problem quite well. I appreciate your help immensely. leonboy gets the check because his answer is more appropriate for the question I asked.

Comment: OK, but please note that the answer is *not* "Poisson distribution"--that's merely an ingredient in the approximate calculation.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand enough about how the approximation works yet. thank you for the clarification.